# Display data table SQL RealTime in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to create application that showing the rows from table in SQL to DataGridView in System Windows Forms Application

The problem is when I am updating the row directly from SQL Management Studio / Other application was Adding / Deleting / Updating the row in the table, my application isnt showing the latest row

I want my application showing the up to date rows in real time (even the other program change the table rows, I want my application displaying updated rows)

How to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is the MS SQL Server facility called "SQL Query Notifications", introduced here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx.

Be forewarned, it is not simple and it may have some scaling issues for multiple clients.

A good tutorial implementation is here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144344/Query-Notification-using-SqlDependency-and-SqlCach

Explanations of the scaling concerns and how to deal with them are in these other SO questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14875804/109122

[Is there a scalable alternative to SQL Server Query Notifications for raising events in an application from SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960126/is-there-a-scalable-alternative-to-sql-server-query-notifications-for-raising-ev?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this when I am home :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SqlDependency` Class. Its intended use is mostly for ASP.NET pages (low number of client notifications).

```
ALTER DATABASE UrDb SET ENABLE_BROKER
```

Implement the OnChange event to get notified:

```
    void OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    And in code:

    SqlCommand cmd = ...
    cmd.Notification = null;

    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);

    dependency.OnChange += OnChange;
```

It uses the Service Broker (`a message-based communication platform)` to receive messages from the database engine.

Answer (score -1):

Create trigger on insert operation.
This trigger must fire update event for you application.
Aplication recieve event and update table.

You neet only choose communication protocol

Comment: You might want to explain how you think "*This trigger must fire update event for you application*" can be done, because it's far from obvious what you mean here.

Comment: yes please explain more detailed about "trigger update event"